# get total amount for each value for specific key in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

**Array**:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "Test 1",
        eventTypeId: 2,
        eventType: {
            id: 2,
            name: "Event X",
            category: {
                id: 1, 
                name: "Study 1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,   
        title: "Test 2",
        eventTypeId: 2,
        eventType: {
            id: 2,
            name: "Event Y",
            category: {
                id: 1,
                name: "Study 2"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Test 3",
        eventTypeId: 2,      
        eventType: {
            id: 2,
            name: "Event Z",
            category: {
                id: 2,
                name: "Study 1"
            }
        }
    }
];
```

The data comes from `API` request and inside the success `function` I'm attributing the response to `$scope.initialDataLength` as below:

```
var getDataLength = function () {
    $http.get(urlData).success(function (data) {
       $scope.initialDataLength = data;
    }
}
```

**View**:

```
<td class="col-md-2">
   {{ initialDataLength.length }}
</td>
```

But I want to get the length of the `name` of the `Category` object.

I was trying something like:

```
angular.forEach (data, function (typeId) {
    var type = typeId.eventType;
    angular.forEach (type, function (category) {
        var cat = category.name;
        console.log("cat", cat.length)
    })
});
```

But it shows me the following error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Could anybody explain me, where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need the inner `forEach()`. You already have the object reference and you just need to access properties of that object

```
angular.forEach (data, function (typeId) {

    console.log(typeId.eventType.category.name)

});
```

Comment: @Anton If I were you I would make a verification to test if the `category !== undefined` or you'll get some problems if the category comes as empty object. Just a suggestion..